# There is a way to obtain the ID of the facebook person that wrote to my page using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im building a external link to my facebook page conversation with a person, processing the data provided by facebook api.
I want something like this: //inbox/ example:facebook.com/104218061964937/inbox/100071153377218
i already have the page id , but I have problems to find the person id that writes.

Answer (score 0):

This message seems to be from a profile to a page, by looking the url .
To have the data from a message, you should use the pages api, than you ask for pages_messaging permission, and make a get request to the inbox node .
The question is not clear, you should give better details, i dont see dificulty to find ids from anything, as a page .

Comment: view a better explication of my case below you answer